# How to hide imagebutton?

Tags: android

I have 1 imageButton and i want to hide that button after 5sec in oncreate method. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 9):

```
onCreate(){
  new SleepTask().execute();
}

private class SleepTask extends AsyncTask{
  protected void doInBackground(){
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(){
    yourImageButton.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ImageButton inherits from View so you can always use:

[imageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

In order to have the view disappear after x amount of time you can use a handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

   public void run(){
       imageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   } 

}, 5000);//delayed 5 secs
```

Ensure to call this after you are done with everything of the view and after setContentView or onViewCreated (for fragments) is called

Comment: `imageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` also disables the button, i.e. it's like `imageButton.setVAlpha(0);` *and* `imageButton.setEnabled(false);` which might not be welcome if you only want to make the button disappear.

Answer (score 1):

imageButton.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
or
imageButton.setVisible(View.GONE);