# How can I hide and show some ImageButtons?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi guys I'm new on android programming and I have many problems with xml. Some hours ago I asked you how to hide a layout and all was solved [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251426/how-can-hide-show-some-parts-of-my-layout-solved/26252037#26252037). Anyway I try as I've seen in many other questions to hide and show some ImageButtons but not only ImageButtons won't show, now neither the Layout want to show :/

This is my code:

```
public class Hide_Unhide extends Activity {

    LinearLayout barrainfo;

    ImageButton icotelefono;
    ImageButton icoemail;
    ImageButton icofacebook;
    ImageButton icotwitter;
    ImageButton icosito;


    ImageButton prova;

    public Hide_Unhide (View v){
        barrainfo = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.links_bar);         //tutta la barra

        icotelefono = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.telephone_icon); //pulsante chiamata
        icoemail = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.email_icon);         //pulsante nuova mail
        icofacebook = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.facebook_icon);  //pulsante facebook
        icotwitter = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);     //pulsante twitter
        icosito = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.sito_icon);       //pulsante sito web

    };

    public void mostra_nascondi(int numero_di_informazioni, int info_number){   //numero di informazioni = 0 (no info) - 1 (si info)
        /*if (numero_di_informazioni <= 0){                                     //info_number = identifica il social o il telefono o l'email
            barrainfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                 //se per l'info_number = 3 corrisponde un numero informazioni = 0 
        }else                                                                   //il locale non ha l'email
        {                                                                       //
            barrainfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                              //  - - - Schema Informazioni - - - - - - - - - -  
                                                                                // - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        }*/                                                                     // | 2: telefono   | num_di_informazioni [0-1]   |
                                                                                // | 3: email      | num_di_informazioni [0-1]   |
                                                                                // | 5: facebook   | num_di_informazioni [0-1]   |
                                                                                // | 6: twitter    | num_di_informazioni [0-1]   |
                                                                                // | 7: Google+    | num_di_informazioni [0-1]   |
                                                                                // | 8: Instagram  | num_di_informazioni [0-1]   |
                                                                                //  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  

        switch (info_number){
        case 0:
            if (numero_di_informazioni <= 0){   
                barrainfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                 
            }else                                                                   
            {   
                barrainfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                                                                              
            }
            break;

        case 2:     //telefono
            if(numero_di_informazioni <= 0)
            {
                icotelefono.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                icotelefono.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        case 3:     //email
            if(numero_di_informazioni <= 0)
            {
                icoemail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                icoemail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }           
            break;
        case 5:     //facebook
            if(numero_di_informazioni <= 0)
            {
                icofacebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                icofacebook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        case 6:     //twitter
            if(numero_di_informazioni <= 0)
            {
                icotwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                icotwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        case 7:     //sito
            if(numero_di_informazioni <= 0)
            {
                icosito.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                icosito.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*XML Snippet code:*

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/links_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_bar"
        android:background="#222222"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/telephone_icon"
            android:id="@+id/telephone_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#222222"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
            android:id="@+id/email_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/telephone_icon"
            android:background="#222222"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon"
            android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_icon"
            android:background="#222222"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/twitter_icon"
            android:id="@+id/twitter_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook_icon"
            android:background="#222222"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/sito_icon"
            android:id="@+id/sito_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twitter_icon"
            android:background="#222222"
            android:visibility="gone"/>




    </LinearLayout>
```

*Call to "mostra_nascondi()":*

```
Hide_Unhide metodo = new Hide_Unhide(v);

            int numero_informazioni=0;
            tvnomeditta.setText(Dati_history[indice_riga][nome_luogo]);         //Stampo il nome del posto
            tvindirizzoditta.setText(Dati_history[indice_riga][indirizzo]);     //Stampo il suo indirizzo

            if(Dati_history[indice_riga][telefono].equals("")){         //scompare/appare se c'è il num di telefono
                numero_informazioni=0;
            }else
            {
                tot_informazioni++;
                numero_informazioni++;
                metodo.mostra_nascondi(numero_informazioni,telefono);
            }


            if(Dati_history[indice_riga][descrizione].equals("")){              //Se una descrizione esiste la stampo altrimenti 
                tvdescrizione.setText("Nessuna descrizione");           //scrivo "Nessuna Descrizione"

            }else
            {
                tot_informazioni++;
                numero_informazioni++;
                tvdescrizione.setText(Dati_history[indice_riga][descrizione]);
            }



            if(Dati_history[indice_riga][email].equals("")){        //mostra/scompare icona mail
                numero_informazioni = 0;
            }else
            {
                tot_informazioni++;
                numero_informazioni++;
                metodo.mostra_nascondi(numero_informazioni,email);
            }



            if(Dati_history[indice_riga][facebook].equals("")){     //mostra/scompare icona facebook
                numero_informazioni = 0;
            }else
            {
                tot_informazioni++;
                numero_informazioni++;
                metodo.mostra_nascondi(numero_informazioni,facebook);
            }



            if(Dati_history[indice_riga][twitter].equals("")){      //mostra/scompare icona twitter
                numero_informazioni = 0;
            }else
            {
                tot_informazioni++;
                numero_informazioni++;
                metodo.mostra_nascondi(numero_informazioni,twitter);
            }



            if(Dati_history[indice_riga][sito].equals("")){     //mostra/scompare icona sito web
                numero_informazioni = 0;
            }else
            {
                tot_informazioni++;
                numero_informazioni++;
                metodo.mostra_nascondi(numero_informazioni,sito);
            }
```

Thank you everybody.

Comment: you dont have a break for `case 0`

Comment: @tyczj ok .. I correct but it doesn't work anyway. Thank you I edit my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975141/how-to-hide-imagebutton
Look at this link

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but you don't have switch case for 1, neither default one.

Comment: @user3738027 already did this if you see my code, but it doesn't work. The difference between GONE and INVISIBLE is that with Gone is like the item don't exist in the xml file, with Invisible is like the item is transparent

Comment: Your code about showing and hiding seems correct. Can you post the xml defining this layout? And how and when the method mostra_nascondi() is called? Your switch() statement doesn't cover all cases, maybe it needs a default clause to be sure you're not missing something.

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado I debug it, the debugger enter well in the code and execute all without errors as it should do.

Comment: @think01 Ok I will paste you the code you request. The cases are all covered, I'm sure, I pass only that values.

Comment: @think01 here you are

Comment: Another clarification: is this the complete code for the Hide_Unhide activity? if this is the case, it's incomplete since nobody sets or inflate the layout from the xml (you said the whole layout doesn't show).

Comment: Try removing android:visibility="gone" from your linearlayout. Parent must be visible in order to show any of its children

Comment: @think01 yes this is the complete code for the Hide_Unhide activity

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado nothing to do :/ not work

Comment: Then I don't understand how you use the layout. Where do you set it as layout for the displayed activity? From what I see, the Hide_Unhide activity seems empty and just used to call the setVisibility() method.

Comment: Sorry, the Hide_Unhide isn't an activity. Is a class that extend Activity that I used to hide and show the layout (links_bar). It doesn't have a layout

Comment: Try changing LinearLayout height to android:layout_height="fill_parent". Maybe wrap_content is "0dp" because all its children have visibily gone

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado nothing to do

Comment: Maybe the problem is elsewhere, up in your app's hierarchy. You need to  set the layout (the xml file you posted) as the content in an Activity and show the activity to the user. Then you can manipulate widget as you're doing (and what Juan is saying seems reasonable to me).

Comment: @think01 wait. The layout I posted have been already set to an activity. This morning I used it to show and hide the entire layout as you can see there: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251426/how-can-hide-show-some-parts-of-my-layout-solved), so in this afternoon I try to show and hide buttons. With no results :(

Comment: Thx. Then I don't understand why you created the second activity (Hide_Unhide): why don't you call the setVisibility() from the "real" activity that owns the widgets? Maybe there's an issue about proper calling GUI operations. Have you tried to start with all buttons visibile?

Comment: @think01 because the real activity need an application and from a class that extend application I can't change visibility in the xml

Comment: Every button is placed depending on the previous one, but the first has not specified its position. Maybe they are visible but "out" the screen. Try with the property android:align_ParentLeft="true" for the "telephone" button

Comment: Nothing to do @JuanAguilarGuisado

Comment: Sorry but you do need an Activity to display something so I still don't understand. Can you please post the Application code where you set/inflate your xml layout?

Comment: nope...you don't understand again. The layout is inflated for an Activity and I need an application class to use a matrix with some data. And from the application class I call an activity (hide_unhide) to make some changes on the layout of another activity

Comment: I suggest to verify the layout and the activity work as expected setting visibility="visibile" to all widgets in your xml layout.

Comment: @think01 if I set all to visible I see all buttons in every case...is like the set command from java not working. Now they are everytime turned "ON"

Comment: My suspect is that you're calling the setVisibility() on an object that is not the actual widget displayed. For this reason I'm asking for the inflating code: maybe you have the activity with the real layout on one side, and the Hide_Unhide activity that is working uselessy on other objects that are not actually displayed.

Comment: @think01 I solved with some try and retry and retry finally I solved !! :D I edit my answer thank you so much !! The problem was in the xml. I set visible the layout and gone the buttons...all works now :D

Comment: Then Juan was right many comments ago ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much @think01!! I'll post it as an answer in case Pierpaolo could mark as resolved, cause I spent time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `android:visibility="gone"` from your `LinearLayout`. Parent must be visible in order to show any of its children